# Ubuntu remote access

Tags: remote

I have two pc in a network, now I'm far away from that PC, so because of this I installed Teamwiever. At the moment I can reach one PC(on that pc is running windows 7), I can reach the other PC as well(running ubuntu) but I get only a black screen(after some topic, the reason is the screen saver) :( this is my problem. I want to add some task to the ubuntu.

Is there any way to connect to the Ubuntu PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to instal ssh-server combined with vnc4server.
You can logon through putty using (add a tunel also).
Than you can acces with vncviewer.